# Softlayer API: limitation on Concurrent job API calls?

Tags: rest, powershell, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I tested Windows VM upgrades & downgrades by using PowerShell cmdlet (`Invoke-WebRequest`) and REST API (Softlayer API).
I searched concurrent API calls at once this website. The answer is 50 calls.
But I confirmed test result 20 calls at once.
What exactly about limitation on concurrent API calls (= HTTP requests at the same time)?

Comment: You'll probably have to take that up with the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

the API limitation according Softlayer is 50 api call per second for user, if you have more than that you will get an error saying that you exceed the rate limit.

regards